# How to execute "pip install script"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation

I am following this tutorial found here: https://www.javacodemonk.com/post/101/image-manipulation-detection-in-python

It includes the following line:

`from script.ndimage import gaussian_filter`

But in order to run it, I have to install script first. According to the tutorial, this is how I should install it:

`pip install script`

However, when I execute this line, this is the error I get:
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement script (versions: )
No matching distribution found for script".

(pip is already upgraded to the latest version)

What is the correct way to install "script"?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: if you are using python3, you will need to use pip3 in order to install the correct version

Comment: working code is here: https://medium.com/@upu1994/image-manipulation-detection-c2b461e41a35
Will update the code on site as well as there are new updates in image_slicer library

Comment: Thank you Upasana! You have another typo in it as well. "copy" instead of "coppy". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it probably means scipy rather than script.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#smoothing-filters

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial looks broken. The [script package on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/script/) doesn't have a `ndimage`. Probably it's been broken by a spell check - i imagine it should be `scipy`.

Don't spell check your code, kids!

Comment: I did try scipy, but then I faced other errors. So I thought perhaps they really meant to use "scirpt". Thank you! +1